# How can i get parameter from model into view in AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

hello guys im new in codeigniter and using AJAX.
so i want ask a simple question

i want to parsing data from parameter into model in ajax

so when i open the page the datatables is showing table from query i made in model

this is my snippet code:

**THE VIEW**

```
<?php 
//echo form_open('redo/edit_simpan');
     //echo form_open('person/insert_detail');   
    foreach ($data->result() as $v) {
            $id         = $v->id_request;
            $unit       = $v->unit_permintaan;
            $dokumen    = $v->nomor_dokumen_pendukung;
            $tanggal    = $v->tanggal;
            $status     = $v->status;
        }
```

?>

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//datatables
table = $('#table').DataTable({ 
    
    "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
    "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
    "order": [], //Initial no order.

    // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
    "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo site_url('barang/ajax_list/')?>/",
        "type": "POST"
    },

    //Set column definition initialisation properties.
    "columnDefs": [
    { 
        "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
        "orderable": false, //set not orderable
    },
    ],

}); }
```

**Controller**

```
public function ajax_list()
{
    $list = $this->barang->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $person) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $person->nama_barang;
        $row[] = $person->jumlah_barang;
        $row[] = $person->satuan_barang;
        $row[] = $person->keterangan_barang;

        //add html for action
        $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_person('."'".$person->id_request."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_person('."'".$person->id_request."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="edit_data/'.$person->id_request.'" title="Add_Detail" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Barang</a>';

    
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $output = array(
                    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                    "recordsTotal" => $this->barang->count_all(),
                    "recordsFiltered" => $this->barang->count_filtered(),
                    "data" => $data,
            );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

**MODEL**

```
    function get_datatables($idreq)
{
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
    $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
    
    $this->db->where('id_request',$idreq); //paramter
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

> I want to get parameter ***$idreq*** to showing into datatables on
> view any clue how?
>
> the data i want to is $no = $v->$id_request into model in get_datatables($idreq)

Comment: from where the value of `$idreq ` is passed in your model?

Comment: Thanks Hek mat, from the view, in the top, in variable on $no i want parse data from $no into my model ($idreq)

Comment: does it is same with  `$_POST['start'`];?.I mean the value of $idreq and $_POST['start'] is same or different?

Comment: thankyou again, but its different just same name of variables, sorry for that, any clue?

Comment: i was change $no in the top of my view, into $id, now u can see the difference. i want to my $id is my parameter of my get_datatables($idreq)

Answer (score 0):

In view first load model like this..

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```

Then pass data to model's function like this ..

```
$this->model_name->get_datatables($id);
```

Comment: thank you for helping me, but now it didnt show any data in datatables.

Comment: thankyou for answering, im still new in web programming sorry.
i want to parsing data from $id (in the top of my code view), into my model in function get_datatables($idreq),
so, $id (view) -> $idreq (model)
if my $id = 14 it will parsing data into my $idreq in model